# How to create ramdisk block device on Fedora 17?

Tags: linux, fedora, storage, ramdisk

In Fedora 16 `/dev/ram*` got removed and replaced with `tmpfs`.

However `tmpfs` can't make block devices.

**Question**

How do I make a ramdisk block device in Fedora 17?

Answer (score 1):

```
yum install MAKEDEV
MAKEDEV ram
```